# While using selenium.WebDriver I getting an error : missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get content from ::after element. I wrote this code, but I get an exception:

---

"OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: "javascript error: missing ) after argument list

---

I'm using VSC+selsenium-webDriver+c#.
I did tried to escape quotes it didn't help. How can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
 string script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#bbc-morph-sport-football-header-event-EFBO1065913 abbr[data-reactid *='94.0.1.0'] > span'),':after').getPropertyValue('content')";

        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        string content = (string)js.ExecuteScript(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by using the browser's console to test your JS statements. For example, Chrome's console has useful syntax highlighting and you will see, where is the problem with brackets and quotes.

Comment: I fixed code like this ```return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#bbc-morph-sport-football-header-event-EFBO1065913 abbr[data-reactid *=\'94.0.1.0\']'),':after').getPropertyValue('content');```and no mistake shows. It still dosen't work.

Comment: JS code works but does not do what you want, or you sill have the same exception?

Comment: While you execute the same JS in the browser's console, it works correctly?